# Keep temporary std::string and return c_str() to prevent memory leaks

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-leaks, stdstring

I found myself using this type of code below to prevent memory leaks, is there anything wrong with it in terms of performance, safety, style or ...?

The idea is that if i need to return an edited string (in terms of a c-string not std::string), i use a temporary std::string as a helper and set it to what I want my return to be and keep that temporary alive.

Next time i call that function it re-sets the temporary to the new value that I want. And since the way i use the returned c-string, I only read the returned value, never store it.

Also, I should mention, std::string is an implementation detail, and dont want to expose it (so cant return std::string, have to return c-string).

Anyway, here is the code:

```
 //in header
class SomeClass
{
private:
    std::string _rawName;

public:
    const char* Name(); // return c-string
};

//in cpp file
std::string _tempStr; // my temporary helper std::string

const char* SomeClass::Name()
{
    return (_tempStr = "My name is: " +
            _rawName + ". Your name is: " + GetOtherName()).c_str();
}
```

Comment: Why not just return `std::string` and let callers decide what to do with it? Also, how do you use more than 2 instances of your class without obliterating `_tempStr`?

Comment: What happens if I have 2 SomeClasses and I want to store both names somewhere? They share the same underlying string so it wouldn't work. It's better to just return a `const std::string&` instead.

Comment: "_std::string is an implementation detail, and dont want to expose it_", what a strange restriction to put on yourself.  Unless this is cross a shared object boundary, just _use the library_.

Comment: *so cant return std::string, have to return c-string*  If you're going to go that route, you might as well have the user pass in their buffer and you fill it in with the information.  An "implementation detail" would only arise if that function is being called from a language other than C++ where a `std::string` doesn't exist, or across module boundaries (as the previous comment mentioned).  Otherwise, you're doing a whole lot of busy work for nothing -- just return a `std::string`.

Comment: Don't use C++ if your goal is to use C...

Comment: Lets say I have a good reason not to return std::string for example SomeClass is exported (with '__declspec(dllexport)' ) and It is declared in a DLL and used in an another program. Also the return is not supposed to be stored.

Comment: When phrased like that, the question is 'how do I return a string in C interface'. The answer is - you ask the caller for the char[] buffer and size of this buffer, and than populate the buffer with result. Pretty much like snprintf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ you cannot simply ignore object lifetimes.  You cannot talk to an interface while ignoring object lifetimes.

If you think you are ignoring object lifetimes, you almost certainly have a bug.

Your interface ignores the lifetime of the returned buffer.  It lasts "long enough" -- "until someone calls me again".  That is a vague guarantee that will lead to really bad bugs.

Ownership should be clear.  One way to make ownership clear is to use a C-style interface.  Another is to use a C++ library types, and require your clients to match your library version.  Another is to use custom smart objects, and guarantee their stability over versions.

These all have downsides.  C-style interfaces are annoying.  Forcing the same C++ library on your clients is annoying.  Having custom smart objects is code duplication, and forces your clients to use whatever string classes *you* wrote, not whatever they want to use, or well written `std` ones.

A final way is to type erase, and guarantee the stability of the type erasure.

Let us look at that option.  We type erase down to assigning-to a `std` like container.  This means we forget the type of the thing we erase, but we remember how to assign-to it.

```
namespace container_writer {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  template<class C, class It, class...LowPriority>
  void append( C& c, It b, It e, LowPriority&&... ) {
    c.insert( end(c), b, e );
  }

  template<class C, class...LowPriority>
  void clear(C& c, LowPriority&&...) {
    c = {};
  }
  template<class T>
  struct sink {
    using append_f = void(*)(void*, T const* b, T const* e);
    using clear_f = void(*)(void*);
    void* ptr = nullptr;
    append_f append_to = nullptr;
    clear_f clear_it = nullptr;

    template<class C,
      std::enable_if_t< !std::is_same<std::decay_t<C>, sink>{}, int> =0
    >
    sink( C&& c ):
      ptr(std::addressof(c)),
      append_to([](void* ptr, T const* b, T const* e){
        auto* pc = static_cast< std::decay_t<C>* >(ptr);
        append( *pc, b, e );
      }),
      clear_it([](void* ptr){
        auto* pc = static_cast< std::decay_t<C>* >(ptr);
        clear(*pc);
      })
    {}
    sink(sink&&)=default;
    sink(sink const&)=delete;
    sink()=default;

    void set( T const* b, T const* e ) {
      clear_it(ptr);
      append_to(ptr, b, e);
    }
    explicit operator bool()const{return ptr;}
    template<class Traits>
    sink& operator=(std::basic_string<T, Traits> const& str) {
      set( str.data(), str.data()+str.size() );
      return *this;
    }
    template<class A>
    sink& operator=(std::vector<T, A> const& str) {
      set( str.data(), str.data()+str.size() );
      return *this;
    }
  };
}
```

Now, `container_writer::sink<T>` is a pretty darn DLL-safe class.  Its state is 3 C-style pointers.  While it is a template, it is also *standard layout*, and standard layout basically means "has a layout like a C struct would".

A C struct that contains 3 pointers is ABI safe.

Your code takes a `container_writer::sink<char>`, and inside your DLL you can assign a `std::string` or a `std::vector<char>` to it.  (extending it to support more ways to assign to it is easy).

The DLL-calling code sees the `container_writer::sink<char>` interface, and on the client side converts a passed `std::string` to it.  This creates some function pointers *on the client side* that know how to resize and insert stuff into a `std::string`.

These function pointers (and a `void*`) pass over the DLL boundary.  On the DLL side, they are blindly called.

No allocated memory passes from the DLL side to the client side, or vice versa.  Despite that, every bit of data has well defined lifetime associated with an object (RAII style).  There is no messy lifetime issues, because the client controls the lifetime of the buffer being written to, while the server writes to it with an automatically written callback.

If you have a non-`std` style container and you want to support `container_sink` it is easy.  Add `append` and `clear` free functions to the namespace of your type, and have them do the required action.  `container_sink` will automatically find them and use them to fill your container.

As an example, you can use `CStringA` like this:

```
void append( CStringA& str, char const* b, char const* e) {
  str += CStringA( b, e-b );
}
void clear( CStringA& str ) {
  str = CStringA{};
}
```

and magically `CStringA` is now a valid argument for something taking a `container_writer::sink<char>`.

The use of `append` is there just in case you need fancier construction of the container.  You could write a `container_writer::sink` method that eats non-contiguous buffers by having it feed the stored container fixed sized chunks at a time; it does a clear, then repeated appends.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0cdcf54d4740d85a)

Now, this doesn't let you return the value from a function.

To get that to work, first do the above.  Expose functions that return their strings through `container_writer::sink<char>` over the DLL barrier.

Make them private.  Or mark them as not-to-be-called.  Whatever.

Next, write `inline public` functions that call those functions, and return the filled `std::string`.  These are pure header file constructs, so the code lives in the DLL client.

So we get:

```
class SomeClass
{
private:
   void Name(container_writer::container_sink<char>);
public:
   // in header file exposed from DLL:
   // (block any kind of symbol export of this!)
   std::string Name() { 
     std::string r;
     Name(r);
     return r;
   }
};

void SomeClass::Name(container_writer::container_sink<char> s) 
{
  std::string tempStr = "My name is: " +
        _rawName + ". Your name is: " + GetOtherName();
  s = tempStr;
}
```

and done.  The DLL interface *acts* C++, but is actually just passing 3 raw C pointers through.  All resources are owned at all times.

Comment: I read the first paragraph and was like "this sounds like Yakk..." :)

Answer (score 4):

This is a mistake. If you pass a pointer as a return value, the caller must have a guarantee that the pointer will remain valid as long as necessary. In this case the pointer could be invalidated if the owning object is destroyed, or if the function is called a second time causing a new string to be generated.

You want to avoid an implementation detail, but you're creating an implementation detail that is much worse than the one you want to avoid. C++ has strings, use them.

Answer (score 1):

This might backfire if you ever use your class in multi-threaded environment. Instead of those tricks, just return std::string by value.

I have seen the answer about 'implementation detail'. I do not agree with it. std::string is no more implementation detail than const char*. It is a way to provide string representations.

Comment: I don't think you understood the answer you're talking about.

Comment: @Barry, the later clarification (regarding being in DLL) was added after I updated my answer. When I was updating, it simply stated std::string being implementation detail.